# How to add adapter in recyclerview after onCreate()

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView set up which should display a list of movies. The thing is that I get the data after I made an API call. So my question is: How am I able to set the Data after the onCreate method of my Activity?

```js
// Fragment

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_overview, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        movieOverviewPresenter.loadMovies();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void showMovie(List<Movie> movies) {
        mAdapter = new MovieOverviewAdapter(movies);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

// Presenter

    @Override
    public void loadMovies() {
        retrofit.create(MovieService.class).getPopularMovies("API_KEY").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.i("Request", "Success!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d("Request", "Error: " + e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Result result) {
                        mView.showMovie(result.getResults());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: you can set data in `onResume()` for example. But what is the problem?

Comment: Well I have a method which is called after the API call. I'd like to use that. My problem is that I get an error when I try to set the adapter later on: **No adapter attached; skipping layout**

Comment: Can you show what have you done?

Comment: I think you need to post your code to get better help from us. Also, where do you call your after the API call method?

Comment: I added the code reference

Comment: Did you try to set adapter in `onCompleted` method?

Comment: Yes, I believe the problem is that I cannot set the adapter after the layout is inflated. Does somebody know a workaround?

Comment: Checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/30581896/3836557.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to tell the adapter that the data has been updated after a while by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `onComplete()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Call showMovie() in onResume().